# "Unexpected end of command - line 1, column 8" in JetBrains DataGrip trying to connect to Firebird

Tags: intellij-idea, firebird, jetbrains-ide, datagrip, jaybird

I'm trying to connect to a Firebird database hosted in a Docker from the DataGrip client, but this error appears:

> WARNING: No connection character set specified (property lc_ctype, encoding, charSet or localEncoding
> [42000][335544851] Dynamic SQL Error; SQL error code = -104; Unexpected end of command - line 1, column 8 [SQLState:42000, ISC error code:335544851]

[image: WARNING: No connection character set specified (property lc_ctype, encoding, charSet or localEncoding), defaulting to character set NONE]

I've tried to give a path in the file encoding, but I don't have any idea to how Jaybird works.

[image]

What do I need to do?

Comment: The problem is not that warning, because it is just a warning. The problem is the error below that warning, which is caused by the fact that IntelliJ/DataGrip wants to execute a keep-alive/test-query, but it doesn't have a default query configured for Firebird.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by IntelliJ (DataGrip is based on IntelliJ) executing a "keep-alive query" when testing the connection, but the default configuration for the Firebird driver doesn't have a keep-alive query. When no keep-alive query is configured, IntelliJ seems to execute the query `select 1` (though I haven't verified this, the fact the error mentions "column 8" seems to hint at that). This causes Firebird to return an error, because Firebird requires a from-clause.

To solve this, go to the "Drivers" tab of the "Data Sources and Drivers" screen, select "Firebird" (under "Basic Support"), and on the options tab, enter the "Keep-alive query" `select 1 from rdb$database`.

As an aside, you can make the warning about the connection character set go away by explicitly configuring a connection character set (property `charSet`) on the "Advanced" tab of the connection configuration.

I reported this to JetBrains: [Configuration for Firebird misses default keep-alive query causing error on connection test](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-306833/Configuration-for-Firebird-misses-default-keep-alive-query-causing-error-on-connection-test)